# What level of technical detail is appropriate and on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion

I just answered the question, [How can I modify a low cost hobby servo to run 'freely'?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-i-modify-a-low-cost-servo-to-run-freely). In my answer, I talk about inductive loads and back EMF.

Is this kind of content regarding robotics-controlling hardware on topic for the site?

The bigger question: **What level of technical detail is appropriate for this site?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would encourage highly technical answers, but with the proviso that you try to tailor your answers to the questioner. A beginner will need a slow introduction, before being exposed to a load of technical jargon, for example.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the question is relevant to robotics (which is an entirely separate problem), I think that the technical detail of an answer is fine as long as it:

- answers the question
- supplies insight to better understand the problem and solution

In the case of your specific answer, I thought it was good because it answered the question briefly, while still giving some interesting insight that helped to motivate your specific solution.

Robotics is, at its core, an interdisciplinary field; the hardware part is just as important as the software, and sufficient detail should be given about the hardware if it affects understanding of the problem at hand.