# Appropriate to send high school students from a robotics competition here?

Tags: discussion

I am one of the organizers of [a robotics competition](http://www.robo-crc.ca) for high school students. We're entering our 14th year. Over the years, the students have amassed a fairly sophisticated level of technical knowledge, expertise and understanding, which has been passed down institutionally.

One of the keys to our competition is that *all* of the work on their robots must be performed directly by students. So, while adult expert 'mentors' are available, they only offer guidance and may not always have an answer to a particular question.

So, in a vaguely similar vein to [What level of technical detail is appropriate and on-topic for this site?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-level-of-technical-detail-is-appropriate-and-on-topic-for-this-site) (and my not being new to the Stack) I wanted to check with this group to ensure that it would find it appropriate for us to actively direct students here as part of their resource pool.

I think it would be a great resource, and offer the young students a chance to engage with professionals and expert hobbyists alike. But I also understand that the context of Stack Exchange is not geared to this, specifically. Would it be worthwhile (for us) to ask students to provide some context if they chose to post here, such as their age bracket? I know I read a "silly" question on Stack Overflow from an identified struggling high school student differently than from someone I perceive to be a professional web developer.

I also fully accept and agree with the necessity to close and down-vote bad questions for the good of **this** community (which is essentially why I'm asking).

If relevant, we provide VEX-based base kits to student teams, and a few motors, but they are not limited to that. For example, some have interconnected Arduino boards and sensors to automate some tasks.

NOTE: I have [posted a similar question to Electonics.SE Meta](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/appropriate-to-send-high-school-students-from-a-robotics-competition-here), as they are closely linked themes, but distinct communities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I certainly have no problem with students asking questions here, but as with all questions they need to be sufficiently well researched, clear questions appropriate for this site.

Questions which don't live up to the standards of quality expected should be questioned, commented upon and ultimately edited to attain the quality they need.

I don't think there is any need for people to explicitly flag themselves as students. If the question is already good enough then it won't add anything and if it isn't good enough then fixing the question is more important than blaming anyone. Many good questions have come from the seeds of poorly written, poorly understood questions which have been through multiple revisions to make them clearer.